# Deleting a file over SAMBA, server is seeing 1MB/s upload

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, samba, server-message-block

Server: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.
Client: Win7 professional 64 bit.
Creds: account on server. no domain, no kerberos.
Samba config: stock. shares have very simple access retrictions like writeable on, readonly off, user is in writeable list.

mapped network drive to folder on server, server has multiple shares.
tried doing a Shift+Del of a file the user owns and Win7 brings up the Calculating status of the file transfer dialog. browsing other folders in another samba window was very slow.
used ifstat to see if the server was getting generic heavy networ traffic. it was.

```
1.47      3.67      0.00      0.00
7.53      7.43      0.00      0.00
11.66     11.99      0.00      0.00
0.46      0.33      0.00      0.00
51.63    203.65      0.00      0.00
38.91    697.66      0.00      0.00
32.13   1250.75      0.00      0.00
30.25   1159.47      0.00      0.00
36.02    743.04      0.00      0.00
24.48   1014.20      0.00      0.00
24.17    949.62      0.00      0.00
29.57    899.95      0.00      0.00
27.28   1077.61      0.00      0.00
31.00   1080.59      0.00      0.00
24.78    951.00      0.00      0.00
25.47   1014.25      0.00      0.00
34.25   1096.53      0.00      0.00
30.10   1142.80      0.00      0.00
50.76    925.73      0.00      0.00
49.28    829.43      0.00      0.00`
eth0                tun0
KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out
52.33    467.71      0.00      0.00
37.32    511.89      0.00      0.00
9.11    193.29      0.00      0.00
1.23      0.15      0.00      0.00
0.33      0.15      0.00      0.00
1.21      0.72      0.00      0.00
15.46     15.10      0.00      0.00
10.64      9.83      0.00      0.00
0.91      0.33      0.00      0.00
0.91      0.63      0.00      0.00
0.54      0.15      0.00      0.00
0.41      0.15
```

stopped file delete, ifstat went back to normal. tried shift delete again and captured the above paste.

why is this?